# SVN authentication to Active Directory using SASL and OpenLDAP

Tags: svn, gentoo, sasl

I have been following all of the guides I found online to get a working svnserve + SASL + OpenLDAP configuration and I had everything working for about a day and then after playing with svn+ssh for a bit I somehow must have broken something and can't get it working again.

In my /srv/svn/repo/conf/authz file I have listed Active Directory groups like this:

```
Admins = User One, User Two
Engineers = Other User, Someone Else
```

It's using the CN of each user for those groups, which worked before, but now the only way I can get my SVN client to authenticate is if I specify the username instead of the CN for those groups in my authz file.

Here are my configs (on a Gentoo system, edited the domain name and password for security):

/etc/conf.d/saslauthd:

```
SASLAUTHD_OPTS="${SASLAUTHD_OPTS} -a ldap"
```

/etc/saslauthd.conf:

```
# LDAP auth/lookup settings
ldap_servers: ldap://domain.com
ldap_default_domain: domain.com
ldap_search_base: DC=domain,DC=com
ldap_bind_dn: CN=LDAP Bind,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com
ldap_bind_pw: password

# AD Options
ldap_deref: never
ldap_restart: yes
ldap_use_sasl: no
ldap_start_tls: no
ldap_version: 3
ldap_auth_method: bind
ldap_filter: sAMAccountName=%U
ldap_password_attr: userPassword
ldap_timeout: 10
ldap_cache_ttl: 30
ldap_cache_mem: 32768
ldap_mech: PLAIN
```

/etc/sasl2/svn.conf:

```
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
auxprop_plugin: ldap
mech_list: PLAIN LOGIN
ldapdb_mech: PLAIN LOGIN
```

/srv/svn/repo/conf/svnserve.conf:

```
[general]
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
authz-db = /srv/svn/repo/conf/authz
realm = Engineering

[sasl]
use-sasl = true
min-encryption = 0
```

I cannot figure out what could have changed when I was playing with the svn+ssh options that I would have forgotten to revert back when I realized it wouldn't work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Exactly what error message do you get when you attempt to connect?